# Is it possible to publish a node package by cloning other's?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, package, publish

I need to use a node package in React Native.

But it requires a minor fixes for React Native bundling.

So I want to do something like this.

```
1. Clone the node package
2. Do minor updates for React Native(dependencies, update some codes for React Native)
3. Publish
```

Is this possible?

Is this violation of privacy policy?

Can I publish under node package owner's license?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the project is on GitHub, you could fork the repo, make your changes, and in your package.json use your own copy of the project like so, without having to re-publish it to npm:

```
"dependencies": {
  "thepackage": "git://github.com/username/thepackage.git"
}
```

With regards to the licensing question however, you'll have to look into the specific license of the package you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can [npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) a git repo as a package, instead of publishing a minor fix copy.